Excel LEN Function Returning Wrong Count - More than the characters count in cell
Facing a very strange situation while using Excels LEFT, RIGHT, LEN functions on a cell. Cell contains a numeric value (00361941) to be exact. When I try to use LEFT(Cell,6), it gives 00361 (should be 003619), when I use RIGHT(Cell,6), it gives 61941‬ (should be 361941).
Then I tried to find the length of the cell, it strangely, it gave me 10, when the characters count is 8.
I tried using CLEAN(), TRIM(), CLEAN(TRIM()) functions to remove any spaces or other characters, still getting the same results. I even tried to do a CTRL+H to replace any CHAR(10), CHAR(13) and CHAR(160) characters with some other value, still same results.
Any leads to resolve or find out the exact issue, please.

You probably have an ' in front of the numbers that is hidden. Use mid instead of left.

Please include screenshot of 1) selected cell including formula bar, 2) selection of the cell including the left formula returning undesired result. 3) same for right and len. Regardless the above your value is likely not a numerical value if it includes leading 0-s, but you may have a look in the formatting.

I encountered the CHAR(160) a few hours ago. What you're reporting tells us that you have a leading and another trailing invisible character. Use =CODE(LEFT(A1,1))&", "&CODE(RIGHT(A1,1)) to identify them. If the result is e.g. 158, 158, use =SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(158),"") to get rid of them.

You can research the text using formula:
=CODE(MID($A$1,A2,1))


It shows the character codes char by char.

Invisible Characters

After playing around for a while, I concluded it is safer to use UNICODE and UNICHAR as indicated by nkalvi in your comments. I put your number between two characters described as U+200C ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER on [this page])(https://invisible-characters.com/).

I used the following formulas to deal with the issue:
=UNICODE(LEFT(A1,1))&", "&UNICODE(RIGHT(A1,1))
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,UNICHAR(8204),"")

(8204 is decimal, 200C is hexadecimal.)

The screenshot tells the rest of the story.

Could you share some feedback about what happened in your case to make your post useful for others?



